# Set permision to an app in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, app-permissions

I try to add the workflow identifier at `site app permissions` when I set app id then click `lookup` button , but the title and app domain not retrieved !?

What's the reason for this ?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you set the app identifier correctly ? Make sure that you copied the client section of the App Identifier between the last “|” and the “@” sign

Comment: Yes. And when click lookup button not retrieved

Comment: are you tried to do this via IE or Chrome ?

Comment: Yes i tried both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general reasons for this issue are

- You may don’t select the client section of App Identifier correctly.
- you don't [configure App Managment Service](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/26/create-and-configure-app-management-service-in-sharepoint-server-2013/).
- “`Workflows can use app permissions`” feature was not activated.
- “`Workflows can use app permissions`” feature was activated before configuring App Managment Service.

To solve this issue for the above reasons check [granting permission to an app in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/30/lookup-an-app-id-was-unable-to-retrieve-its-related-data-during-granting-permission-to-an-app-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thanks , i didn't configure APP Management service , now i configure it but the lookup button still not working(:

Comment: are you check Workflows can use app permissions features if activated or not if activated deactivate it then activate it again , if not activated try to activate it

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Good news, Should you set this as answer and upvote if it helped you and solved your issue , you should check also this tour http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to can do it

Comment: I am sorry i am newbie in community , thanks again for your worth help and tour link